# How to read Binary Device Object Store (BOS) descriptor of USB Device on Linux

Tags: linux, usb, device, lsusb

I need to programmatically read device descriptors of a USB device plugged into a Linux system (Ubuntu 18.04). I can read most of the descriptors I need (iSerial, iProduct, etc) by parsing *lsusb* output, or by reading directly from the *usbfs* files at `/sys/bus/usb/devices/`. However I'm having trouble finding the Binary Device Object Store (BOS) descriptor using either method.

I imagine I can query the BOS using *libusb* but it seems like since this is a USB spec standard descriptor, there may be a simpler way. Is possible read it directly from the *usbfs*, or query it from a standard utility tool like *lsusb* or other?

Comment: I do see the BOS of a USB 3 device using _libusb_ (Version 007, Ubuntu 18.04) here.

Answer (score 1):

BOS descriptor can be get through control transfer. The control transfer parameters are:

bmRequestType: 0x80,
bRequest: 0x06,
wValue: 0x0F00,
wIndex: 0x0000,

The header BOS descriptor is:

```
struct usb_bos_descriptor_header {
    u8_t bLength;
    u8_t bDescriptorType;
    u16_t wTotalLength;
    u8_t bNumDeviceCaps;
};
```

We can also use https://github.com/libusb/libusb/blob/master/examples/xusb.c to get BOS descriptor.